# How to get a value coordinates from a function and write to in geojson object?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

I created a function that will draw a polygon and take the coordinates of the polygon

```
draw.on('drawend',function(e){
  console.log(e.feature.getGeometry().getExtent())

})
```

In the console, the log output coordinates
Array(4)

13188645.953365186

13247283.87535125

16003266.208696177

16491915.558580033

[Screenshot of received coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH1DL.jpg)
The values must be collected along the X, Y coordinate in square brackets
    'coordinates':[[13188645.953365186, 16003266.208696177], [13188645.953365186, 16491915.558580033Y2]]

```
 'coordinates':[[X1, Y1], [X2, Y2]]
```

so that I can in geojson instead of  'coordinates': [[[7464176.08307154,12392090.249458816],[8109193.224918226,14454190.505968675]]]
could enter his coordinates received in function **draw.on**

```
var geojsonObject = {
        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'crs': {
          'type': 'name',
          'properties': {
            'name': 'EPSG:3857'
          }
        },

          'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'Polygon',
            'coordinates': [[[7464176.08307154,12392090.249458816],[8109193.224918226,14454190.505968675]]]

      }
```

Coordinates will always change dynamically ,
How can I write them into a geojson object in 'coordinates': how to write it down so that it understands, and changes the coordinates if the event occurs and new coordinates appear

It is necessary to obtain coordinates in this way

```
 'coordinates':[[X1, Y1], [X2, Y2]]
```

Comment: you want to create [[a,b],[c,d]] from [a,b,c,d] ?

Comment: yes  and write the values ​​to the geojson object

Comment: you get the linear coordinates array, then why you can't make it to 2-demension array?

Comment: on these two points a polygon is built, and I need to write down values from function to an object in the format  [[a,b],[c,d]]

Comment: doesn't it something like `coords = [a, b, c, d]` to `[[coords[0], coords[1]], [coords[2], coords[3]]]` ?

Comment: just the whole problem is where you need to create a variable coords.Because they are stored in a function draw.on

Comment: when do you need geojson then?

Comment: after the function event draw.on I get the coordinates and they need to be used in geojson

Comment: Nope, I mean, you can put the coordinate into geojson once draw end triggered. so when exactly geojson should be ready to use?

Comment: geojson must be ready immediately after the event has triggered, and will change if the event occurs again

Comment: just update coordinates of geojson by overriding when `drawend` triggered. you can access it `geojsonObject.geometry.coordinates`. I'm getting confused if this is only about basic `javascript` question.